# How to select records that fall between start time and end time where end time is for next day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am working on the discount to allow discount to be applied when ordering on specific time.

Everything is working fine, but I have a weird request from customers. My customer has a midnight special. They want to create a special with up to 50% off (based on $$$ amount order) when their customer placing their order within 2 hours window (from 11pm - 1am).

As you can see, 1am is for the next day. So, it is *from 11pm **today** to 1am **next day***

Currently here is my stored procedures (it will select the best discount based on total spend):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspGetBestDiscount]
(
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @TotalSpend FLOAT = 0,
    @OrderDate DATETIME = NULL,     --NULL to use today date.
    @DiscountRate FLOAT = NULL OUT,
    @DiscountId INT = NULL OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@OrderDate IS NULL) SET @OrderDate = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @OrderTime TIME = CAST(@OrderDate AS TIME)

    SET @DiscountId = NULL; SET @DiscountRate = NULL;
    SELECT TOP 1 @DiscountId = [DiscountId], @DiscountRate = [DiscountRate] 
    FROM [tblDiscount]
    WHERE (@TotalSpend >= [MinSpend]) AND
          (@OrderTime >= CAST([StartTime] AS TIME)) AND
          (@OrderTime <= CAST([EndTime] AS TIME)) AND
          ...
          ...
          ...
    ORDER BY [DiscountRate] DESC;
END;
```

Everything is working fine as long as `StartTime <= EndTime`. Any idea how to make **EndTime** as next day when `StartTime > EndTime`?

Thanks

Comment: use dateadd function

Comment: @Thebeginner - yes, but I couldn't workout how to use dateadd as the start time and end time date is always 01/01/1970 (this is because start time and end time don't care about the date, just the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE (@TotalSpend >= [MinSpend]) AND
(
    (
        /* E.g. 8pm - 10pm: */
        (
            CAST([StartTime] AS TIME)
                <
            CAST([EndTime] AS TIME)
        )
            AND
        (
            (@OrderTime >= CAST([StartTime] AS TIME))
                AND /* Note: AND */
            (@OrderTime <= CAST([EndTime] AS TIME))
        )
    )
        OR
    (
        /* E.g. 11pm - 1am: */
        (
            CAST([StartTime] AS TIME)
                >
            CAST([EndTime] AS TIME)
        )
            AND
        (
            @OrderTime >= CAST([StartTime] AS TIME)
                OR /* Note: OR */
            @OrderTime <= CAST([EndTime] AS TIME)
        )
    )
)
...
```